# python: find in subprocess's output, leave it running and continue

Tags: python, subprocess

I was have to call a shell command

```
subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I did it. and:

and, that command is prints lots of things like verbose is on, and then when its done it's job it prints (writes) `blah blah : Ready`

I have to call this command, wait for the 'Ready' text and leave it running on background, then let the rest of the code run

I tried this *and things like this*, didn't work

```py
...
done=False
with subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
  while not done:
    x=proc.stdout.read()
    x=x.find('Ready')
    if x > -1:
      done=True
  print("YaaaY, this subprocess is done it's job and now running on background")
  #rest of the code
```

i ran similar (edited) code on python terminal and I think I can't even access (read) the terminal  of the subprocess. because...
[image: console stuck waiting]

I was expecting it will show every line that this subprocess print but. its just waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `proc.stdout.read()`. This reads the entire output of your subprocess, which is not known until it has terminated (usually). Try something like:

```py
output = b''
while not done:
  output += proc.stdout.read(1)
  x = output.find(b'Ready')
  if x > -1:
    done = True
```

This reads the process's stdout one character at a time, so it doesn't have to wait for it to finish.

Note that using `Popen` in a context manager (`with` block) will cause your program to wait for the child process to terminate before it exits the `with` block, so it will not leave it running past that point. It's unclear if that is desired behaviour or not.

Comment: it works thanks and that line must `output = output + str(proc.stdout.read(1), 'utf-8')` because without utf-8 output becomes like 'a',' ','b', 'i', 't', ' ','w', 'e', 'i', 'r', 'd'. and find doesn't work... it works with `output = output + str(proc.stdout.read(1), 'utf-8')`. and thanks :)